# How can I change the default size (width + height) of the XML layout preview in ADT plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: android

Every time that I want to do a Layout, I'm getting a black layout preview then I can drop stuff on it, that's ok, but how can I change the size of that blank surface (xml). The question came because I set a folder layout-large and then when I add a new layout.xml to that folder it came with the same size, as a layout-normal, so I’ve something like that



(folder)layout
    layout.xml

(folder)layour-large
    layout.xml

Both file has the same physical or visible size, how can I increase the large one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a toolbar above the preview where you can choose device (ADP1 by default).
You can change it to Nexus One (800x480) or create you own device with custom resolution and select it.

[image]

Comment: Afeter that any device with 320x480 or more will pick the layout from that folder that it just creates instead from layout folder?

Comment: Yes, it will create a folder for you, but you can remove it after. As far as I know there is no other way to change preview resolution. Anyway my advice will be to test layout on emulator or real device because preview is often useless.

Comment: let's see if i understood, by doing this I'll have  a new folder beside the current layout folder right? .. so any screen different that 320x480 will go to layout folder and any screen 320x480 will go to that new folder so i need to keep both, am I right??

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding I recommend you to read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html